# How can I get access to he absolute URL in Symfony and go one level up?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, absolute-path

My absolute URL is linked to my public folder:

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('img/logo/image.jpg')) }}" alt="image"/>
```

It works fine like this, but in one case I need to load an image with an absolute URL but not to the public folder, instead, the image is in another folder that is on the same level then my public folder. I tried something like this:

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('../myfolder/private/image.jpg')) }}" alt="image"/>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place? Why not put assets in the asset folder?

Comment: Because we programmed a module that is generating thumbnails within that modul. It is complicated to explain this all here, but for this it is necessary

Comment: I would assume that this is a security feature, so assets can not be linked from outside the configured folder

Comment: Look into [Packages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html) possibly. Do that on the server-side as pass it in as a twig variable since this is a one-off. If you need it multiple times you should be able to create a quick twig extension to do handle your logic.

Comment: If you u need it in `DOMPDF`, then use the physical path

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, this is my problem. I cannot figure out how to create a physical path to the root

Comment: You could pass the absolute path from your controller to twig with something like `__DIR__ . '/../../path/to/file/image.jpg';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public` is your webroot, you can't access anything outside `public` directly in your browser (and for good reasons, this means you can't read the source code of any application!)

If you want to make something from outside the `public` directory available, either move it (or symlink) it into the public directory, create a new webroot, or write a custom Symfony controller to show the assets to your clients (make sure to have proper caching with the latter solution).